# Process list of two different types

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have two types / classes `Missile` and `TrackingMissile`. Where `TrackingMissile : Missile` and `TrackingMissiles` override its base `Update` method.

Missiles `Update` implementation is:

```cs
void Update()
```

Whereas I want the tracking missile type to have an additional argument.

```cs
void Update(Vector2 target)
```

I then want a collection of missile with `List<Missile>`. If this was Typescript I would implement it with a union type and during iteration I would do some pattern matching.

Basically aiming for this invalid code:

```cs
List<Missile> missiles = new List<Missile> {
    new Missile(...),
    new TrackingMissile(...)
};

foreach (var missile in missiles) {
    if (missile is Missile) missile.Update()
    else if (missile is TrackingMissile) missile.Update(target)
}
```

Here it seems it is `TrackingMissile` is somehow cast somewhere or such. One way I could do is two implement two lists of different types but this is desired as it is not maintainable when I want to implement more derivations of `Missile`.

tldr: what is the best way I can maintain a collection of different types and during iteration run different logic based on their type.

Comment: `if (missile is TrackingMissile tm) tm.Update(target); else missile.Update();` -- put the more specific type first, because *both* are Missile. You could also make Update() virtual and give it a Target parameter which is unused when unneeded. Or it might make sense have TrackingMissile keep track of its own target, and not pass that as a parameter.

Comment: What about if you change the order of `if/else`. `if (missile is TrackingMissile) missile.Update(target);
    else if (missile is Missile) missile.Update()`

Comment: You could use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching). `if (missile is TrackingMissile tm) tm.Update(target); else missile.Update();`

Comment: Why not implementing `void Update(Vector2 target)` for `Missile` and ignore `target` when it's not `TrackingMissile`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko although true it's bad practise as the base Missile does not require `target` ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you are using c# 7.0 or higher you can use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching).

```
List<Missile> missiles = new List<Missile> {
    new Missile(...),
    new TrackingMissile(...)
};

foreach (var missile in missiles) {
  if (missile is TrackingMissile tm) {
    tm.Update(target);
  } else { 
    missile.Update();
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, my original idea was true, it seems the order is important to make sure it doesn't always fall into its base class

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *same interface* for all missile classes:

```
 public class Missile {
   ...
   // In case of untracking missile we ignore its target
   public virtual void Update(Vector2 target) 
     => Update();

   // No target: just moving forward
   protected void Update() {...}
 }

 public class TrackingMissile : Missile { 
   ...
   // In case of tracking missile we put target into account 
   public override void Update(Vector2 target) {...}       
 }
```

By doing this you can easily create new missile types without changing `foreach` logic

```
 public class GuidedMissile : TrackingMissile { 
   ...
   public override void Update(Vector2 target) {
     // If target has been captured by radar
     if (IsTargetCaptured(target)) 
       base.Update(target); // ... approach to the target, 
     else 
       Update();            // otherwise just move forward
   }
 }
```

And so you can put

```
List<Missile> missiles = new List<Missile> {
  new Missile(...),
  new TrackingMissile(...),
  new GuidedMissile(...)
};

// Whatever missiles launched, update their locations
foreach (var missile in missiles)   
  missile.Update(target);
```